Clicking on an item throws error
When a user clicks on a particular item alone she is encountering a 500 custom error page. Below is the stack trace from log.
This issue is happening for one particular user and not for all.

Call Stack: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication+CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Web.HttpException handled at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError:
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FillNamedControlsTable (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.FindControl (Sitecore.Kernel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.BindControls (Sitecore.Kernel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.CreateControls (Sitecore.Kernel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnInit (Sitecore.Kernel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
, Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.


Can she click on other items ok, or does every item fail? Also have you tried clearing browser cache and cookies?

Hi @RichardSeal The issue is happening only on clicking one particular item. After clicking that item and consequent click on any other item throws error.

@christopherraja If that item is accessible to other users then please check the access rights for the user for which it is not happening. It cab be one of the reasons.

@RichardSeal Akshay Barve The issue was happening for one particular author only and on one laptop only. However applying the below changes in the config fixed the issue and has been included in the code repo as well.​
